# PopOS installed on my external SSD connected with USB not recognizing by my computer

Tags: dual-boot, usb-drive, pop-os

I installed PopOS on my 128 GB SSD, which is externally connected to my pc via USB port. Windows 11 is installed on my laptop's main SSD (on the motherboard). When I install PopOS for the first time and not plugged of my external SSD since, on boot menu I can select PopOS on every boot. I can plug off my USB without booting into Windows. But when my computer boot windows by default when my external SSD is not connected to my PC, I can not select PopOS from boot menu further on. I have tried different installation processes, but result was same. What may cause my PC not recognizing PopOS after I boot windows when my external device is not connected?

Comment: What computer is it (brand name and model)? There should be a hotkey (for example F12, but different between computers) to get a temporary boot menu, where all available bootable drives should be shown. And this *should* be independent of what was run before.

Comment: I'm using MSI GL73-8RD. Hotkey is F11. I am totally agreed that it should be but it is not somehow. I've installed ubuntu to my portable SSD and it appears on the boot menu even if my device is not connected as it should be.

Comment: If an operative system, that is not connected, appears on the boot menu in UEFI mode, I think there is an entry for it in the EFI system partition (in the internal drive, so alongside the entry for Windows 11). But I am confused: what is your problem (except that your Linux system shows on the boot menu even when not connected)? Can you boot into your PopOS system? via the F11 menu? via a grub menu at a normal boot? or both one none of them?

Comment: Before I've installed Ubuntu, PopOS was not showing on the boot menu which I open with F11 hotkey even when connected. I removed PopOS and installed Ubuntu. I think Ubuntu installed its own boot settings alongside to Windows boot manager (Windows is installed in my SSD on the motherboard). The reason PopOS not showing on boot menu might be it could not manage to do that.

Comment: I have a lot of experience of Ubuntu. I have tried PopOS  too, but not much, so I don't know more than you about how it is different from Ubuntu, and how it can fail. Anyway, Linux is free, so try different distros and stay with a distro that can do what you want :-)